# Php DateTime Add and Subtract not affecting

Tags: php, datetime

Please help me solve this. I am not getting proper output on this code. Is this a bug in datetime add/sub functions or I am doing something wrong?

```
function CallAndSave($startTfr = '')
{
    $interval       = new DateInterval('P91D');
    $GBofficialTime = new DateTime('2014-02-01T08:52:37');
    if ($startTfr == '')
    {
        $startTfr = $GBofficialTime->sub($interval);
        echo"SF=" . $startTfr->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s') . "<br>";
    }

    $endTto = $GBofficialTime->add($interval);
    echo"GB=" . $GBofficialTime->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s') . "<br>";
    echo"SF=" . $startTfr->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s') . "<br>";
    echo"ET=" . $endTto->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s') . "<br>";

    $date = new stdClass;
    $date->StartingDateFrom = $startTfr->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s');
    $date->StartingDateTo = $GBofficialTime->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s');
    $date->EndingDateFrom = $startTfr->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s');
    $date->EndingDateTo = $endTto->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s');

    echo "SF=$date->StartingDateFrom <br>";
    echo "ST=$date->StartingDateTo <br>";
    echo "EF=$date->EndingDateFrom <br>";
    echo "ET=$date->EndingDateTo <br>";
    return;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
SF=2013-11-02T08:52:37
GB=2014-02-01T08:52:37
SF=2014-02-01T08:52:37
ET=2014-02-01T08:52:37
SF=2014-02-01T08:52:37 
ST=2014-02-01T08:52:37 
EF=2014-02-01T08:52:37 
ET=2014-02-01T08:52:37
```

The datetime operation is applied only on this code

```
if ($startTfr == '')
{
    $startTfr = $GBofficialTime->sub($interval);
    echo"SF=" . $startTfr->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s') . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working correctly for me. You're subtracting, echoing once, adding, then echoing the rest. Remember that `->add` and `->subtract` work on the instance. They change the date the instance holds.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Are you getting the same output as I have in my question or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`\DateTime::sub()` manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php#refsect1-datetime.sub-returnvalues):-

> Return Values
>
> Returns the DateTime object for method chaining or FALSE on failure.

This means that in your code

```
$GBofficialTime = new DateTime('2014-02-01T08:52:37');
if ($startTfr == ''){
    $startTfr = $GBofficialTime->sub($interval);
    echo"SF=" . $startTfr->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s') . "<br>";
}
```

`$GBofficialTime` and `$startTfr` are referencing the same object. They are not seperate objects, so you are, in fact, subtracting `$interval` from `$GBofficialTime`.

To avoid this side affect, you need to clone `$GBofficialTime` before calling any mutators:-

```
$GBofficialTime = new DateTime('2014-02-01T08:52:37');
if ($startTfr == ''){
    $startTfr = clone $GBofficialTime;
    $startTfr->sub($interval);
    echo"SF=" . $startTfr->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s') . "<br>";
}
```

You have the same issue further on in your code with `$endTto`, the solution is, of course, the same.